# UART Transmit Rs232 to USB

Tags: serial-port, vhdl, uart

I have A UART transmitter written in VHDL and want to transmit data from FPGA Rs232 to a PC that only has a USB.
My question is, is it fundamentally a correct assumption that USB can receive serial data? I'm basically treating the USB as an Rs232 receiver.

If this is correct, what program can allow me to monitor the USB incoming data?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You created a hammer but you needed a screwdriver.  An RS-232 to USB converter is *very* common and costs but a few bucks, you need to go shopping.

Comment: Yea I do have that cable. My question is that is this a correct approach to send the data from Rs232 to a pc through USB? is there a program that tells me what data goes in the USB port such as putty

Comment: It is correct when it works.  If it doesn't work then you did something wrong, nobody can guess what that might be.

Comment: To monitor USB see http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/Category:USB_Monitoring_Tools.

Answer (score 0):

USB port includes 1 differential data line + 2 power line, that makes 4 cable(I mean version <= usb2.0).

RS232 is full duplex data transmission protocol which you can't do it with USB2.0(USB3.0 is full-duplex). And it has additional control lines. It doesn't include power line. It has variable voltage levels(up to +-25V).

Simply, yes you need a converter.

[USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB)
[RS232](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232)